# OSGI import package issue

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, equinox

i have a curious behavior about bundle wiring.

I have a bundle A which needs javax.xml.bind.* package to use JAXB.
The TargetPlatform contains the bundle  javax.xml.bind_2.2.0XXX.jar which exports those bundle with the version 2.2.0.

I specify the required packages in the bundle A manifest using Import-Package and specifing the same version as exported (ie. 2.2.0).

So, i expect those packages to be the one exported by the bundle javax.xml.bind.XXX.jar.

When i run the code which needs those Jar on JRE which do not provide javax.xml.bind.*, everything works fine.

When i run under another JRE which do not provide them, then i have a classCastException on JRE/rt.jar.

For the second case, it seems the classes from JRE is used instead of the ones from the bundle.

If i change the bundle A manifest to Require-Bundle on the required bundle, everything works fine.

When i use the console "packages javax.xml.bind" command to see what bundle are providing the package, i have the expected result (the package is provided by the system bundle and the javax.xml.bind).

As the command, show, the system bundle does provide the package under the version 0.0.0, so it should not be used.

Do anyone have any clue about what i missed?

[console Result]

> packages javax.xml.bind
>   osgi.wiring.package; bundle-symbolic-name:List="org.eclipse.osgi,system.bundle"; bundle-version:Version="3.13.100.v20180827-1536"; version:Version="0.0.0"; osgi.wiring.package="javax.xml.bind"
>   osgi.wiring.package; bundle-symbolic-name="javax.xml.bind"; bundle-version:Version="2.2.0.v201105210648"; version:Version="2.2.0"; osgi.wiring.package="javax.xml.bind"

[Manifest]

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.indy.libraries;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 19.1.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: js.jar,
 saxon9.jar,
 saxon9-xpath.jar,
 xml-apis.jar,
 .,
 bsf.jar,
 resolver.jar,
 serializer.jar,
 xercesImpl.jar,
 commons-logging-1.1.jar,
 saxon9-sql.jar,
 saxon9-jdom.jar,
 saxon9-s9api.jar,
 ant.jar,
 ant-contrib-0.6.jar,
 ant-launcher.jar,
 ant-nodeps.jar,
 ant-trax.jar,
 trang.jar,
 lib/global/rmiio-2.0.2.jar
Export-Package: com.indy.libraries,
 com.thaiopensource.relaxng.input,
 com.thaiopensource.relaxng.output,
 com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate,
 com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate.util,
 com.thaiopensource.xml.sax,
 net.sf.saxon,
 net.sf.saxon.charcode,
 net.sf.saxon.codenorm,
 net.sf.saxon.event,
 net.sf.saxon.evpull,
 net.sf.saxon.expr,
 net.sf.saxon.exslt,
 net.sf.saxon.functions,
 net.sf.saxon.instruct,
 net.sf.saxon.java,
 net.sf.saxon.jdom,
 net.sf.saxon.number,
 net.sf.saxon.om,
 net.sf.saxon.pattern,
 net.sf.saxon.pull,
 net.sf.saxon.query,
 net.sf.saxon.regex,
 net.sf.saxon.s9api,
 net.sf.saxon.sort,
 net.sf.saxon.sql,
 net.sf.saxon.style,
 net.sf.saxon.sxpath,
 net.sf.saxon.tinytree,
 net.sf.saxon.trace,
 net.sf.saxon.trans,
 net.sf.saxon.tree,
 net.sf.saxon.type,
 net.sf.saxon.value,
 net.sf.saxon.xpath,
 org.apache.tools.ant,
 org.apache.tools.ant.types,
 org.apache.xml.serializer
Import-Package: com.ctc.wstx.stax;version="4.4.0",
 javax.xml.bind;version="2.2.0",
 javax.xml.bind.annotation;version="2.2.0",
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters;version="2.2.0",
 org.codehaus.stax2;version="3.1.4",
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.jdom;version="1.0.0",
 org.jdom.input;version="1.0.0"
Bundle-Vendor: %Bundle-Vendor
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.indy.libraries.build;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.indy.libraries.engine;bundle-version="1.0.0";visibility:=reexport,
 com.indy.ui.custom.out;bundle-version="17.2.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-Activator: com.indy.libraries.LibrariesPlugin
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: com.indy.libraries.build,
 com.indy.libraries.engine
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true`enter code here`
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Comment: You missed showing us the manifest of your bundle ;-)

Comment: Here is the manifest:

Comment: OMG what a mess. Well, best guess is that you are doing `Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.runtime` which has a transitive (i.e. reexported) requirement on `org.eclipse.osgi`, the system bundle. But there is way too much wrong with this bundle to be confident about a single cause.

Comment: It sure is a mess. You are probably right about the reexported system bundle, this can totally explain the issue. Thanks for the pointer, i really could not figure this out.